# Writing JUnit tests in Jython

Tags: java, web-services, junit, jython

I was wondering whether anyone is using Jython to write JUnit tests? The reason for this is that I try to find a neat way to test my SOAP based web services **without** the need to generate any code. The reason for sticking with JUnit is that I would love to eventually integrate the tests into my Ant based CI system.

I already had a look at the article http://www.devx.com/java/Article/26602/1954 which describes exactly what I need. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get it working.

Any thoughts and experiences on this would be of great help.

Thanks, 
Alex

Comment: did you get any solution? or you are writing test cases in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather go the other way round: write tests using python unittest to test java code from python. You could then have doctests as well to test Java code, which is neat.

Then you could attempt integration in ant by creating an ant task that e.g. runs 'nose' to find and execute the tests.

Or you can decide to use Hudson for continuous integration (which is going a long step beyond simple Ant) and never look back... ;)

A nice article with this and more (including a mention of the jython plugin for Hudson):
http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/TestingIntegration.html

Comment: Hi Carles, unfortunately, it's not up to me to decide what infrastructure should be used... Since all the testing is done with JUnit or testing tools that are based on JUnit it has been decided to stick with it. I'll post some more details of what's not working once I get a chance to look at it in more detail. Thank's for the pointers though! Doctests look pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

I have written jython code to test Java projects in the past. Saves me the headache of typecasting and accelerating the death of my keyboard with excessive keystrokes.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/library.jar')
from com.example.library import Foo

import unittest

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def testFoo():
        bar = (2, 3, 4)
        foo = Foo(bar)
        self.assertIn(2, foo)
```